# WSO2 ESB error on deploying gmail mediator

Tags: wso2, gmail, connector, mediator

I'm following the wso2 gmail connector tutorial [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Using+the+Gmail+Connector#b661038e2b52445e990848b2f9bb02a6) but getting the error,

```
ERROR - MediatorFactoryFinder Unknown mediator referenced by configuration element : {http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse}gmail
```

I followed all the steps mentioned, got my gmail credentials and configured the mediators in the sequence.

What am I missing?

The xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="PaymentRequestProcessingSequence" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property description="Get Email ID" expression="json-eval($.patient.email)" name="email_id" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <call>
        <endpoint key="SettlePaymentEP"/>
    </call>
    <log description="LogPaymentRequestProcessingSequenceRes" level="full">
        <property name="type" value="LogPaymentRequestProcessingSequenceRes"/>
        <property expression="get-property(&quot;INTERNALREQUESTID&quot;)" name="internalrequestID"/>
        <property expression="get-property(&quot;MessageID&quot;)" name="messageID"/>
        <property expression="." name="message"/>
    </log>
    <property description="Get Payment Response" expression="json-eval($.)" name="payment_response" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <gmail.init>
        <userId>myEmail</userId>
        <accessToken>theAccessToken</accessToken>
        <apiUrl>https://www.googleapis.com/gmail</apiUrl>
        <clientId>theClientId</clientId>
        <clientSecret>theClientSecret</clientSecret>
        <refreshToken>theRefreshToken</refreshToken>
    </gmail.init>
    <gmail.sendMail>
        <to>{$ctx:email_id}</to>
        <subject>Payment Status</subject>
        <messageBody>{$ctx:payment_response}</messageBody>
    </gmail.sendMail>
    <drop/>
</sequence>
```

**Stacktrace**

```
    ERROR {org.apache.synapse.deployers.LibraryArtifactDeployer} -  Deployment of synapse artifact failed for synapse libray at : C:\Program Files\WSO2\Enterprise Integrator\6.4.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1546859692950SampeServicesCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car\gmail-connector_3.0.7\gmail-connector-3.0.7.zip : Error while extracting Synapse Library : gmail-connector-3.0.7.zip {org.apache.synapse.deployers.LibraryArtifactDeployer}
org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Error while extracting Synapse Library : gmail-connector-3.0.7.zip
    at org.apache.synapse.libraries.util.LibDeployerUtils.extractSynapseLib(LibDeployerUtils.java:426)
    at org.apache.synapse.libraries.util.LibDeployerUtils.createSynapseLibrary(LibDeployerUtils.java:65)
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.LibraryArtifactDeployer.deploy(LibraryArtifactDeployer.java:60)
    at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.synapse.SynapseAppDeployer.deploySynapseLibrary(SynapseAppDeployer.java:355)
    at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.synapse.SynapseAppDeployer.deployArtifacts(SynapseAppDeployer.java:101)
    at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager.deployCarbonApp(ApplicationManager.java:272)
    at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.CappAxis2Deployer.deploy(CappAxis2Deployer.java:72)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:59)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:67)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxisDeployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:93)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program%20Files\WSO2\Enterprise%20Integrator\6.4.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1546859692950SampeServicesCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car\gmail-connector_3.0.7\gmail-connector-3.0.7.zip (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.synapse.libraries.util.LibDeployerUtils.extract(LibDeployerUtils.java:448)
    at org.apache.synapse.libraries.util.LibDeployerUtils.extractSynapseLib(LibDeployerUtils.java:424)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: Have you checked if the gmail connector is actually installed on your ESB? Check it under connectors in the Management Console. Also, check if it is enabled, when you install it it is by default disabled.

Comment: Is not. But I'm unable to add it.
Gmail connector, `[-1234] [] [http-nio-9443-exec-37] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.library.service.upload.LibraryUploader} -  Error occurred while uploading Carbon App artifacts
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\WSO2\Enterprise Integrator\6.4.0\tmp\synapse-libsuploads\gmail-connector-3.0.7.zip (The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)`

Comment: That at least explains why you get the error. I would not add it using the CAR as it says in the example. Instead, remove that and try installing it separately after.

Comment: Nevertheless, is not extracting the zip. Is it corrupted?
`[EI-Core] ERROR - LibraryArtifactDeployer Deployment of synapse artifact failed for synapse libray at : C:\Program Files\WSO2\Enterprise Integrator\6.4.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1546859692950SampeServicesCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car\gmail-connector_3.0.7\gmail-connector-3.0.7.zip: Error while extracting Synapse Library_gmail-connector-3.0.7.zip
org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Error while extracting Synapse Library: gmail-connector-3.0.7.zip
 at org.apache.synapse.libraries.util.LibDeployerUtils.extractSynapseLib(LibDeploye(...)`

Comment: can you include the complete stacktrace in your question?

Comment: @ophychius, theres the stacktrace.

Comment: Answer to this problem is posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58063547/getting-error-while-adding-gmail-connector-in-wso2-studio-error-while-extractin/59687413#59687413