# Getting error while adding gmail connector in wso2 studio "Error while extracting Synapse Library : gmail-connector-3.0.8.zip"

Tags: wso2, gmail, gmail-api, connector, wso2-esb

I am trying to implement the use case https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Using+the+Gmail+Connector but in my case I am applying the gmail connector in out sequence but while exporting the .car file it is failing with error "error while extracting Synapse Library : gmail-connector-3.0.8.zip"

I have tried adding the gmail connector in console but it is not reflecting yet, also tried restarting the server and redeploying several times but no luck here.

Here is the full image of my project. 
[click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJ3rT.png)

Below is the log and error I am getting.

```
[2019-09-23 18:16:36,147] [EI-Core]  INFO - EventPublisherDeployer Event Publisher deployment held back and in inactive state :MessageFlowConfigurationPublisher.xml, Stream validation exception : Stream org.wso2.esb.analytics.stream.ConfigEntry:1.0.0 does not exist
[2019-09-23 18:16:36,148] [EI-Core]  INFO - EventPublisherDeployer Event Publisher deployment held back and in inactive state :MessageFlowStatisticsPublisher.xml, Stream validation exception : Stream org.wso2.esb.analytics.stream.FlowEntry:1.0.0 does not exist
[2019-09-23 18:16:36,151] [EI-Core] ERROR - LibraryArtifactDeployer Deployment of synapse artifact failed for synapse libray at : C:\Program Files\WSO2\Enterprise Integrator\6.5.0\repository\deployment\server\synapse-libs\gmail-connector-3.0.8.zip : Error while extracting Synapse Library : gmail-connector-3.0.8.zip
org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Error while extracting Synapse Library : gmail-connector-3.0.8.zip
    at org.apache.synapse.libraries.util.LibDeployerUtils.extractSynapseLib(LibDeployerUtils.java:426)
    at org.apache.synapse.libraries.util.LibDeployerUtils.createSynapseLibrary(LibDeployerUtils.java:65)
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.LibraryArtifactDeployer.deploy(LibraryArtifactDeployer.java:60)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
    at org.apache.synapse.Axis2SynapseController.deployMediatorExtensions(Axis2SynapseController.java:746)
    at org.apache.synapse.Axis2SynapseController.createSynapseEnvironment(Axis2SynapseController.java:388)
    at org.apache.synapse.ServerManager.start(ServerManager.java:183)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.initESB(ServiceBusInitializer.java:468)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.activate(ServiceBusInitializer.java:206)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
    at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.persistence.service.InboundEndpointPersistenceServiceDSComponent.activate(InboundEndpointPersistenceServiceDSComponent.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:515)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.removePendingItem(CarbonServerManager.java:291)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.bundleChanged(PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:847)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program%20Files\WSO2\Enterprise%20Integrator\6.5.0\repository\deployment\server\synapse-libs\gmail-connector-3.0.8.zip (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:126)
    at org.apache.synapse.libraries.util.LibDeployerUtils.extract(LibDeployerUtils.java:448)
    at org.apache.synapse.libraries.util.LibDeployerUtils.extractSynapseLib(LibDeployerUtils.java:424)
    ... 61 more
```

Comment: It seems like there is a file missing for the extract process.
Try adding the file ` gmail-connector-3.0.8.zip` to the folder ` C:\Program%20Files\WSO2\Enterprise%20Integrator\6.5.0\repository\deployment\server\synapse-libs\` .

Comment: there seems spaces in the file path . like Progra Files\WSO2\Enterpris Integrator. This might have caused the issue , can you try to install integrator to a folder where there are no spaces and try this again. If it works please report an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who still have this problem:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program%20Files\WSO2\Enterprise%20Integrator\6.5.0\repository\deployment\server\synapse-libs\gmail-connector-3.0.8.zip (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Is because of the spaces in the name path. I've moved my instalation to root, so now it is:

```
C:\WSO2\EnterpriseIntegrator\6.5.0\repository\deployment\server\synapse-libs
```

And that solved THAT problem. Don't forget to update all the environmental variables and also the classpath on the server inside integrator studio.

Did this solve the problem of the project not being able to run due to the below?

```
Unknown mediator referenced by configuration element : {http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse}gmail
```

No it did not..That one happens because the connector is not enabled in that carbon web management console.

As soon as you deploy the connector, or copy the connector to \repository\deployment\server\synapse-libs it will be deployed in the management console, if you click List under Connectors you will see the gmail connector there and the Status will be Disabled, just click it to change to enabled and redeploy the application on the studio.